# Using SqlBotDataStore for bot state falls back instead to state.botframework.com

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm using the Nuget Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure package extensions to store my bot's state. BotBuilder 3.14.0, Bot.Builder.Azure 3.2.5.

I've been successfully using TableBotDataStore up until now, using Azure table storage. On starting a conversation, I can immediately inspect the table and see relevant rows created in it.

I tried using SqlBotDataStore, having run the script to create the table in my (Azure) SQL Server DB. I registered it as per the [sample code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/AzureSql/Global.asax.cs), but on redeployment I find that, although no errors are thrown, no entries are created in the SqlBotDataEntities table, and instead state.botframework.com is being called as part of the request dependencies.

```
var sqlStore = new SqlBotDataStore(ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["SqlBotStorage"].ConnectionString);

builder.Register(c => sqlStore)
                    .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
                    .AsSelf()
                    .SingleInstance();
```

has replaced the (working)

```
var azureTableStore = new TableBotDataStore( 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TableStorageCS"].ConnectionString,
    sBotStorageTableName);

builder.Register(c => azureTableStore)
                    .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
                    .AsSelf()
                    .SingleInstance();

builder.Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(azureTableStore,
                    CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy
                    .ETagBasedConsistency))
                    .As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>()
                    .AsSelf()
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I know the connection string is kosher, as I tried a test in a dummy action method:

```
IBotDataStore<BotData> sqlds = new SqlBotDataStore( 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlBotStorage"].ConnectionString);

var key = new Address("botidhere", "effbee", "uid1", "c1", "x.com");
var bd = new BotData(data: new Dialogs.SimpleResponseDialog("message here"));
await sqlds.SaveAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, bd, default(CancellationToken));
```

and that adds a row just fine.

What else am I missing? The relevant connection string is stored in Azure application settings, as a connection string of type 'SQLAzure':

```
Server=tcp:xxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Comment: It's not a storage account, it's a database connection string. It is correct, as I said above I tried creating an instance of SqlBotDataStore explicitly and it correctly writes to the database.

Comment: Have you tried including CachingBotDataStore registration, with the SqlBotDataStore implementation? I think AzureModule is required, if you are not using CachingBotDataStore (as you've stated in your answer below)

Comment: I didn't bother adding the CachingBotDataStore on top Eric, as it didn't seem to be required in sample code snippets, and my current bot usage isn't so heavy as to warrant any worry about a caching mechanism yet - and, most importantly, I'm still concerned about CachingBotDataStore's possible role in the 3.15 issue of death: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4477

Comment: BTW thanks for the clarification re. using CachingBotDataStore meaning you don't need to register the AzureModule. That would be a handy one to highlight in the docs.

Comment: (issue of death + 1)  ...i think it is finally resolved

Answer (score 1):

I appear* to have fixed it - I was missing the AzureModule registration line:

```
builder.RegisterModule(new AzureModule(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
```

Here's the thing though - this wasn't needed for using TableBotDataStore. Only SqlBotDataStore.

Another thing: adding the line fixed the issue immediately in an Azure deployment slot with a debug build, system.debug=true.  However, deploying to the main webapp (non-slot) with a release build, system.debug=false caused the app to be unable to start. '503 Service Unavailable'. No logs. Reverting immediately to table storage and all was well again.

I'm currently try..catching the above line, but I can't see an exception thrown, yet it has started working now. One to keep an eye on!

*with caveats above...